# How to roll back a database change with Liquibase using classpath

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

My application is using Liquibase to manage database changes. It sets up Liquibase like so:

```
@Bean(name = "liquibase")
public SpringLiquibase liquibaseData() {
    final SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml");
    return liquibase;
}
```

It currently has a single changeset. When the changeset gets applied by running the application, a record is inserted into `DATABASECHANGELOG` as expected with a `FILENAME` of `classpath:/db/changelog/0.0.1/db.changelog.xml`

When I execute a `liquibase rollbackCount 1`, the response is `Liquibase Rollback Successful`, but the change did not get rolled back.

After manually rolling back the change (deleting the table created by the changeset), I do a `liquibase update`. The update is successful, but the `FILENAME` is `db/changelog/0.0.1/db.changelog.xml`. I execute a `liquibase rollbackCount 1`, and the change is rolled back as expected.

This is my `liquibase.properties`:

```
driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
classpath: ../../../../../client-ui/build/libs/client-ui.war
url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
username: the-username
password: the-password
changeLogFile: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

The crux of the problem seems to be that the `FILENAME` is different when the changeset is applied by the application versus the command line. How do I configure the command line parameters so it will create a `DATABASECHANGELOG` record with the same `FILENAME` as what the application creates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that FILENAME is different. Spring sometimes includes the classpath: in their URL which Liquibase just uses. There is code in Liquibase to try to handle the "sometimes there classpath:" prefix, but it sounds like that is not handled correctly in the rollback logic.

There have been some improvements to how the classpath prefix is handled in recent versions, have you tried with Liquibase 3.4.0?

Otherwise, Liquibase update through spring should work correctly with or without the classpath prefix, so if you fix the FILENAME field you should be good. Something like `UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET FILENAME = SUBSTR(FILENAME, 10) WHERE FILENAME LIKE 'classpath:%'` if you are using mysql. You could put a runAlways=true changeSet at the bottom of your changelog file to have it automatically clean up the paths on each update.

Comment: I am using 3.4.0.I implemented your suggested workaround of updating the FILENAME, and was able to rollback changes applied by the Spring app. I ended up making this the first change in the changelog. This forces you to run an extra update command to strip out "classpath:", but has the advantage of making rollbacks easy, since you don't care about rolling back the change to fix FILENAMEs.